# Can't access component method inside 'updated' hook in vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to VueJS and I'm trying to call a method inside a child component after my parent component changed the child's props.

I have the following in my child component:

```
methods: {
    isChecked() {
        if (this.cookiesTags) {
            return this.cookiesTags.includes(this.tag.id);
        }
            return false;
    }
},

updated() {
    this.isChecked();
}
```

However, I get an error saying the isChecked() method is not a function, and I really want to avoid repeating the same code in both the methods and updated() hook.

Am I in the wrong way here? If someone could guide me to a better way of doing this it would be great also. I need to have reactivity in the child's props because the parent component is constantly changing this property via ajax, that's why I used the updated() hook here, but maybe there's a better way.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your code should be working. Look at this fiddle to see what you're doing differently: https://jsfiddle.net/up873ern/1/

Comment: That's true, I tested with a different method name and it works. I'm sure it's because I have a property isChecked in my data() as well as a method isChecked() in my methods. Isn't that supposed to work anyway? And thanks for the help! @thanksd

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I should make this method a computed property, since the method isChecked returns a boolean to the isChecked property, that looks better.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. If you have a property `isChecked`, then it'll overwrite the `isChecked` method. Your vue instance can't have duplicate property names.

Comment: Yes, making it into a computed property makes the most sense in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my mind on that :D